# The error says "missing return statement" but I do not where to put the return statement

Tags: java, methods, return

```
public class BakeryBusiness {
    public static void main(String[] args){  
    }
    public void yearsOfBusiness(){
        int myBusinessStarts = 2023;
    }
    public void itemsToSell(){
        String item1 = "birthdayCake";
        String item2 = "pastry";
        String item3 = "coffee";
        String item4 = "bubbleTea";
        System.out.println(item1);
    } 
    public boolean optionsToChoose(){
        boolean sweetIsChose = true;
        if(sweetIsChose = true){
            System.out.println("You have chose a dessert! What will it be?");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Are you craving for salty foods? Choose what you want!");
            return sweetIsChose;
        }
    }
}
```

where in the optionsToChoose method do I put the return statement? I want to print out "You have chose a dessert! What will it be?"

Comment: Missing return in the _if_ block of `optionsToChoose()`.

Comment: `int myBusinessStarts = 2023;` is also useless as the variable is restricted in scope to this method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from each branch of the method. In your case you are returning from `else` branch but not from `if`.

```
if (sweetIsChose == true)
    System.out.println("You have chose a dessert! What it it be?");
    return sweeIsChose; //<- you were missing this
}
```

A side note you do boolean comparison using `==` but you have used a single `=`, which is for assignment. So it should be `sweetIsChose == true`.

Comment: Never use `==` with booleans, both because of this typo and because it's unnecessary extra.

Answer (score 0):

Only one value is returned if `sweetIsChose` is `false`. So you must specify this in your if statement as well.

```
if (sweetIsChose == true)
    System.out.println("You have chose a dessert! What it it be?");
    return sweetIsChose;
} else {
    System.out.println("Are you craving for salty foods? Choose what you want!");
    return sweetIsChose;
}
```

But since you return the same in both statements, you can make the whole thing a bit clearer:

```
if (sweetIsChose == true)
    System.out.println("You have chose a dessert! What it it be?");
} else {
    System.out.println("Are you craving for salty foods? Choose what you want!");
}
return sweetIsChose;
```

Also a small mistake of yours is that you try to assign a new value to the local variable `sweetIsChose` in the if statement. So instead of `sweetIsChose = true`, use `sweetIsChose == true`. However, you can save yourself the trouble and just pass it to `if (sweetIsChose)`.